# wrapfigure height auto detection

Tags: wrapfig, auto-detection

I am trying to do the number of lines to be narrowed by auto by using `wrapfig.sty`, and my code as follows:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{wrapfig}

\graphicspath{{./Images/}}

\begin{document}

\makeatletter
\newbox\figbox%
\newdimen\figdimen%
\newdimen\fightdimen%

\newcommand{\figcheck}[4][tbp]{%
\setbox\figbox=\hbox{#3}%
\figdimen=\wd\figbox%
\fightdimen=\ht\figbox%
\divide\fightdimen by \strip@pt\baselineskip%
\ifdim\figdimen=27pc%
\begin{wrapfigure}[\strip@pt\fightdimen]{r}{\figdimen}%
#2\par
#3
\end{wrapfigure}\fi}
\makeatother

\figcheck{\caption{Priority health
issues}}{\includegraphics[width=27pc]{fig13a-torus.pdf}}{}
Health is, to a large extent, the result of people's decisions about
health behaviours (such as regular participation in physical
activity) and their everyday experiences as they interact and respond to the social, physical and cultural environments in which they live. However, an individual's level of health is determined by a broader range of factors and not just their health-related decisions. Sociocultural, socioeconomic and environmental factors play a significant role in the achievement of good health. Some factors have the potential for change, such as individuals choosing not to smoke, or governments making roads safer. Other factors, such as an individual's genetic makeup, are generally not modifiable.

\end{document}
```

Above code works fine, as per the wrapfig package, we need to give the number of narrow lines as in rounded value, i.e., 2 or 3, etc, it won't accept the decimal values, and the decimal values are printed as it is, see the screenshot for your reference:

[image]

Please suggest how to fix it by auto.

Comment: `wrapfig` does the estimated line calculation itself. You don't need to give it another one. The optional parameter containing the narrow lines is for manual adaptation if that failed because of the surrounding material.

Comment: Better yet, don't use wrapfig if the image takes up over 0.7\textwidth (like figure[t] won't take over .7\textheight).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following doesn't print the height (this was caused by `\strip@pt`) and uses
only integers in the optional argument of `wrapfig`. However, it is not
necessary to do this computation, as `wrapfig` does it itself if you don't
specify the lines. Also it doesn't consider the additional spaces `wrapfig`
introduces.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{wrapfig}

\begin{document}

\makeatletter
\newbox\figbox
\newdimen\figdimen
\newdimen\fightdimen

\newcommand{\figcheck}[4][tbp]{%
  \setbox\figbox=\hbox{#3}%
  \figdimen=\wd\figbox
  \fightdimen=\ht\figbox
  \ifdim\figdimen=27pc
    \begin{wrapfigure}[\numexpr\fightdimen/\baselineskip\relax]{r}{\figdimen}%
      #2\par
      #3
    \end{wrapfigure}%
  \fi}
\makeatother

\figcheck
  {\caption{Priority health issues}}
  {\includegraphics[width=27pc]{example-image}}{}
Health is, to a large extent, the result of people's decisions about
health behaviours (such as regular participation in physical
activity) and their everyday experiences as they interact and respond to the social, physical and cultural environments in which they live. However, an individual's level of health is determined by a broader range of factors and not just their health-related decisions. Sociocultural, socioeconomic and environmental factors play a significant role in the achievement of good health. Some factors have the potential for change, such as individuals choosing not to smoke, or governments making roads safer. Other factors, such as an individual's genetic makeup, are generally not modifiable.

\end{document}
```

This is what your line calculation results in:
[image]

And this is what happens if you let `wrapfig` do its thing:
[image]